# Winform BindingSource does not get Initialized

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have a few forms where the controls are bound to a BindingSource. I am saving the data to the database when user clicks 'Save' button. The controls are bound so that I do not have to detect the changes manually.

Everything works as expected except when the users close the form and then reopen it. It looks like the BindingSource does not get initialized second/subsequent time. Because the call below returns null on reopen (after setting the datasource)

```
Supplier currentSupplier = (Supplier)supplierBindingSource.Current;
```

The interesting part is that the data gets displayed. So it is successfully setting the data source.

However if I dispose the BindingSource and set it to null on form closed event, then it throws NullExceptionReference on the same code above when the form is shown second time. And this time the code celow in the constructor does not work:

supplierBindingSource.DataSource = qry;

The forms open on a Mdi container. I tried opening as a separate form and also as Dialog. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "reopen"? When the form is closed, the form **instance** should be disposed and the next time a **new** form **instance** should be created and "opened".

Comment: @IvanStoev Exactly. But the binding source is behaving in a way as if the new form instance is somehow acquiring the old BindingSource instance!! I am sure that something else is happening here. As I said above the very first time everything works fine.

Comment: You are the only one who can figure it out. In your form class (and/or form designer generated code) must be a code like `supplierBindingSource = new BindingSource(...`. Put a breakpoint on that line and make sure it executes when you "reopen" the form. I highly suspect it doesn't